# preg_match all the first occurrences and get two matches in a file

Tags: php, regex

**Example string:**

This is a example string with some testing cases \cite{author1,author2}. Then {another example} \citeauthor{author3} and finally \citeP{author1} and string completes here.

**Requirement:** 1. I need to extract the content between {} but after "\cite" string globally.  (eg. \cite{..} or \citeauthor{..})

**I tried:**`preg_match('/[^\\\\cite]{(.*?)}/', $text, $match);//dint work`

2.With the extracted string based on demiliter the string will be exploded.`(eg. if extracted string="author1,author2")` ,then it will be exploded based on "," charac)
 `//it will be done with explode()`

3.If the curly braces is from `(\cite or \citeauthor etc)`, it should be replaced with `for eg. <xref cite>exploded string</xref>` because I want to know whether the string is from `"cite" or "citeauthor" or "citeP".`

4.And I want to replace the string if the exploded string is the first occurrence. `For eg. <xref cite 1>exploded string</xref>`

**Expected output:**
This is a example string with some testing cases `<xref cite 1>author1</xref><xref cite 1>author2</xref>.` Then {another example} `<xref citeauthor 1>author3</xref>` and finally `<xref citeP>author2</xref>` and string completes here.

So,How to get `(\cite or \citep or \citeauthor)` which  has a string between {}
and also the first occurrence of the string in a file.

output=`<xref cite 1>exploded string</xref>` - if I get only string between {} after `\cite` then how can I get `"\cite"` string also with that for every occurrence. 
Thanks for reading. Sorry for the big post, I think it will be understandable

Comment: Ask a single question and don't forget to show your attempts.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What you tried doesn't make much sense, see: [http://regexper.com/#%2F%5B^\\\\cite%5D{%28.*%3F%29}%2F](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5B^\\\\cite%5D{%28.*%3F%29}%2F) (regexper is a useful tool to learn regular expressions by example!)

Comment: I think it is a single question  For every occurrence I need to get, content between {}, then source of curly braces("\cite" or \citeauthor) and the first occurrence of string. So, I need regex based on these requirement

Comment: `\citeP{author1}` is this `P` a mistake? You've told "\cite{..} or \citeauthor{..}" but nothing about this `P`...

Comment: It can be anything...like `\citeP or \citeauthor or \citeNP` but `\cite` is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$s = 'This is a example string with some testing cases \cite{author1,author2}. 
Then {another example} \citeauthor{author3} and finally
\citeP{author1} and string completes here.';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\\\\(cite(?:P|author)?){([^}]*)}/', function($m) {
  return preg_replace('/([^,]+)(?:,|$)/' ,'<xref '. $m[1] . ' 1>$1</xref>', $m[2]); },
  $s);
```

**Output**

> `This is a example string with some testing cases <xref cite 1>author1</xref><xref cite 1>author2</xref>.
>   Then {another example} <xref citeauthor 1>author3</xref> and finally
>   <xref citeP 1>author1</xref> and string completes here.`

Comment: Thanks its perfect. But that 1 is not fixed `(<xref cite 1>author2</xref>)`.If that string is the first occurrence only then 1 should be inserted there. In this `<xref citeP 1>author1</xref>` author1 coming second time so output should be `<xref citeP>author1</xref>`

Comment: How about you take this code and build some additional logic for this in `callback` function.

Comment: Acutally I'm a learner in regex, for my requirement I think regex would be two line steps and fastest way.As I don't know much about regex,how to add first occurrence logic into pattern?

Comment: And also,  in this regex`/\\\\(cite(?:P|author)?){([^}]*)}/` `P or author` is declared. How to pattern for any text in the place of  `(?:P|author)`.eg.`\cite some text{testing}` output should be:`<xref cite some text 1>testing</xref>` I tried:`/\\\\(cite(?:P|author|a-z)?){([^}]*)}/` but dint work.

Comment: one closing bracket is missing

Comment: Yes sorry it should be: `'/\\\\(cite[^{]*){([^}]*)}/'`